# Launching WinRT app from PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-runtime

I have a Windows RT app that I need to launch with a script. I've already installed the app on the device with PowerShell, but I need to launch the app with PowerShell or the command prompt. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

P.S. It looks like there's a way to launch Metro apps on Windows 8 with the Start-MetroApp command, but this doesn't work on Windows RT. Is there some sort of equivalent for Windows RT?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. Please do not close this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use protocol activation, if you want to make your app such that any one can open it from either explorer, run, powershell or cmd

Here's MSDN sample of [protocol activation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec).

Here's the way to launch the app.

For run and explorer : `myapp://`

For cmd and power shell : `explorer.exe myapp://`

Moreover, read this awesome blog post, [Inter-Process communication (Windows Store App & Desktop Apps) with protocol association in WinRT](http://iinspectable.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/inter-process-communication-with-protocol-association-in-winrt-part-3/)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the technique mentioned in [Launch Windows 8 Metro Apps From a Desktop Shortcut or Command Line](http://www.itsjustwhatever.com/2012/10/28/launch-windows-8-metro-apps-from-a-desktop-shortcut-or-command-line/), e.g.:

```
explorer.exe bingnews://
```

It also mentions a [MetroLauncher](http://www.itsjustwhatever.com/downloads/) utility that will work for apps without a protocol.