# How do I launch an application on Windows RT using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, automation, windows-rt

I am working on an automation system and I need to launch the appx applications using a script, PowerShell or otherwise without human intervention(clicking or touching). Is there any way possible for it? What are my options ?

Comment: [Launching WinRT app from PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16025315)?

Comment: Do you just need to launch it or do you expect to interact with it as well? The latter isn't really supported since the applications are intended (and are) sandboxed. You could otherwise automate UI through macro-style testing frameworks (simulating user clicks, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried invoke-item or running basic batch commands?

Invoke-item will run the default behavior for the item so exe should open the application